# Finding a resource that explains the tray above a View Controller Object in Storyboards?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I've found a new way of implementing a UITableViewDataSource object by adding an object to the view controller in storyboards and I'd like to learn more about the area marked in red.  When searching stackoverflow for results pertaining to storyboards I'm given a list of over 4,000 questions pertaining to Interface Builder so this question may be a duplicate.  Where can I go to find a resource online that explains the tray above a View Controller Object in Xcode's storyboards?

Thank you in advance and here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Which part is the "tray"? The rectangle with the four icons? Or the big blank white space?

Comment: The rectangle with the four icons.

Comment: Thx, I guessed that, so I had already typed my answer. Not a very good job circling the object of interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four icons in a horizontal row above the view controller are merely another way (besides the document outline at the left of the canvas) of accessing the top-level objects, both real and proxy, associated with this scene. So the view controller proxy, the first responder proxy, the exit proxy (for unwind seques), and anything *you* introduce at top level.

[image]

In common practice, a very typical fourth object might be a gesture recognizer you've attached to the view (as shown in my screen shot above). But a nib is just a source of objects in general, so you can instantiate anything you like from here (as I presume you are doing).

Answer (score 0):

This is called the "Scene Dock".

This is a duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954223/ios-storyboard-views-outside-of-the-viewcontroller-and-on-top-of-the-scene-bet) (and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39137515/1155375)), as it does not appear to be intuitively named I am submitting this answer for reference.

I took a quick Google through Apple's dev docs to see if I can find some detail, but came up relatively empty. They do appear to reference "scene dock" when discussing adding gesture recognizers to a view controller (just like [matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41472839/1155375)).